# Github action dependency installation failing for Windows

Tags: r, github, github-actions

I am using Github Actions to check my package. It used to work but since recently the installation of some dependencies fails for Windows (but not ubuntu and mac and it also works fine on my Windows PC) with a number of errors:

> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'MSnbase' Error: Error: package
> or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]],
> c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): ERROR: lazy loading
> failed for package 'caret' Error: Error: package 'ggplot2' could not
> be loaded

The complete log can be seen at https://github.com/YasinEl/mzRAPP/runs/2612299525?check_suite_focus=true.
Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the "Install dependencies" step, you'll see that the MSnbase package failed to install, because of an Rcpp version mismatch. This should be a temporary issue, which will go away once Bioconductor builds the binary version of the package so you don't have to compile it as part of the check.

Comment: Thank you, I saw that already but that is a really old Warning which never caused any problem before. Also it explains only the MSnbase problem, but not ggplot2